# Group 2D points in a neighbor with label constraining

Tags: c++, opencv, grouping

I have a set of points in a 2D space. Each of these points is of a structure type that has the following fields:

- 2D Coordinate `(x,y)`
- Label (The label interval can go from 1 up to 4.)

I want to group all the points that lay in the 2D space within a predefined radius `R` in pixels from a point. So if point P1 is near to point P2 they are grouped. If P2 is, in turn, near to P3... P1, P2, and P3 will be considered in the same group although P1 and P3 are not at the desired distance.

However, and here comes the problem for me, two points that have the same label can't be in the same group.

It is important to notice that it can occur that two points with the same label are not within the radius, however, there is another one in the middle of them that is at the correct distance for both of them.

Is there any C++ method to this correctly and fast?

EDIT: I upload some pictures to make understanding easier.

The starting point for the algorithm will be something like this:

[image: First step]

Each color represents a different Label, points in green all have Label = 1, points in red Label = 2 ... So now, the following step will be group these points based on distance

[image: Distance grouping]

However, in the bottom group, there are two green points. This is the condition that must be fulfilled, not two points from the same label in the same group. This will lead to two different solutions which are the ones that I want. (I don't really care which one)

[image: Solution 1] (Green point ungrouped its a group on its own)

[image: Solution 2] (Red and green point are another group)

Comment: Sure there is.  Did you try anything?  Sharing your attempt would be helpful.

Comment: Do you want to minimize the number of groups or what is your goal?

Comment: This general problem can be solved with connected components (from graph theory). You have pairs (edges) of points (vertices), where you only have an edge between Pi and Pj if they don't share the same label and are within the radius. The connected components of this graph are your groups. However there is ambiguity. Say P1 and P3 have the same label, and P2 is within the radius of both and has a different label. Since P1 and P3 can't be in the same group, then you can only have P1 and P2 in a group or P2 and P3 in a group. Which one should you choose? Or do you want both groups in this case?

Comment: I have uploaded some images to clarify, hope now it is easier to understand.

Comment: You did mostly answer the question, but heed @NicoSchertler's question: you said "you don't care which group" you get in the case of this collision. But you can make an explicit rule here which might be better, for e.g. would you rather use the group that has more points in it? Or that gives you more groups at the end? Or that minimizes the number of groups? If it really doesn't matter then just do connected components as I mentioned above, and in this case you only create an edge if the next point is within the radius  and the label isn't present in the component.

Comment: Probably I will say that second solution will be more appropriate, so the number of points in a group will be something to maximize.The number of groups will be undetermined always, and I want to minimize it but taking into account both distance and label conditions. I think I will try connected components from graph theory and see what I get